# Question about interpreting blockchain.info API return

Tags: transactions, blockchain, blockchain.info

When looking at e.g. [this output](https://blockchain.info/rawblock/682500), for the "input" entry in first transaction in the block (i.e. always consist of newly generated coins):
`"inputs":[{"sequence":4294967295,"witness":"01200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","script":"03046a0a046b03966062696e616e63652f626afabe6d6d5eab0f9044182c948a6cc6c4cfcc4c8df66f5839f34cbf36afff532d3eb0188e020000001e34c5f04e198bb203b9000000000000","index":0,"prev_out":{"tx_index":0,"value":0,"n":4294967295,"type":0,"spent":true,"script":"","spending_outpoints":[{"tx_index":6620159290300855,"n":0}]}}]`

I wonder what does it mean by `"value":0,"n":4294967295`. I tried to look up [here](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/e296d83b0442854cb58b709f2a231e3ba7e5530e506937f844b9cdd696ff27bc) in page for the number 4294967295 and found nothing. Also I suspect that the values for "value" and "n" seem to be reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same [transaction using Blockstream.info API](https://blockstream.info/api/tx/e296d83b0442854cb58b709f2a231e3ba7e5530e506937f844b9cdd696ff27bc), that shows is a Coinbase Tx, in my opinion a much clearer output than blockchain.info. As per [Bitcoin Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction#Generation) the sequence number is typically set to 0xFFFFFFFF (decimal: 4294967295), unless transaction's lock_time is > 0.

```
{
  "txid": "e296d83b0442854cb58b709f2a231e3ba7e5530e506937f844b9cdd696ff27bc",
  "version": 2,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "vout": 4294967295,
      "prevout": null,
      "scriptsig": "03046a0a046b03966062696e616e63652f626afabe6d6d5eab0f9044182c948a6cc6c4cfcc4c8df66f5839f34cbf36afff532d3eb0188e020000001e34c5f04e198bb203b9000000000000",
      "scriptsig_asm": "OP_PUSHBYTES_3 046a0a OP_PUSHBYTES_4 6b039660 OP_VER OP_VERIFY OP_2DUP OP_NOP OP_2DUP OP_IF OP_VERIF OP_PUSHBYTES_47 626afabe6d6d5eab0f9044182c948a6cc6c4cfcc4c8df66f5839f34cbf36afff532d3eb0188e020000001e34c5f04e OP_PUSHBYTES_25 <push past end>",
      "witness": [
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
      ],
      "is_coinbase": true,
      "sequence": 4294967295
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "scriptpubkey": "00143156afc4249915008020f932783319f3e610b97d",
      "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_0 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 3156afc4249915008020f932783319f3e610b97d",
      "scriptpubkey_type": "v0_p2wpkh",
      "scriptpubkey_address": "bc1qx9t2l3pyny2spqpqlye8svce70nppwtaxwdrp4",
      "value": 679603284
    },
    {
      "scriptpubkey": "6a24aa21a9edc420b0f8e1264754b5baad9d6424a519a2e12941fecd869747590b577f87b3a3",
      "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_RETURN OP_PUSHBYTES_36 aa21a9edc420b0f8e1264754b5baad9d6424a519a2e12941fecd869747590b577f87b3a3",
      "scriptpubkey_type": "op_return",
      "value": 0
    }
  ],
  "size": 240,
  "weight": 852,
  "fee": 0,
  "status": {
    "confirmed": true,
    "block_height": 682500,
    "block_hash": "00000000000000000007e70fe4af876da9444d3ae9c3283ef859fc1d0cdf9417",
    "block_time": 1620444011
  }
}
```